# How to recover values from JsonObject java

Tags: java, json, intellij-idea

I have a list of JSonObject, I want recover just the values of tow variables in json.

In java 8 I don't find the function getJSONObject,may be it's not recognized..
First of all I added my json to a list of `JSONObject`. But when I want get it, the editor `Intellij` propose just the function get.

Exemple: `records.get(0).get("id")` I got the result bellow, but when I want recover the varible inside like: `records.get(0).get("id").get("875488")...` I got an error.

```
My code:


JSONArray JSONArray = (JSONArray) obj;
List<JSONObject> records = new ArrayList<JSONObject>(); 

    for (int i=0; i<JSONArray.size(); i++) {

        records.add( (JSONObject) JSONArray.get(i) );

    }
```

I tried to recover the first tow value of `"lat"` and `"lon"` but I can't arrived.
Someone can help me please ?

I want like as result:

```
lat = 12.13

lon =  5.02
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off all, the correct Maven/Gradle dependency for JAVA-json is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
```

If the method `JSONObject#getJSONObject` cannot be found, you're doing something wrong.

---

For the code part, that should do it. Adapt to your necessities.

```
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(source);
final int length = jsonArray.length();

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    final JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    final JSONObject forecastOrig =
            jsonObject.getJSONObject("875488")
                      .getJSONObject("forecast_orig");

    final double lon = forecastOrig.getDouble("lon");
    final double lat = forecastOrig.getDouble("lat");

    System.out.println(lon);
    System.out.println(lat);
}
```